# What are the rights of un-married girls to choose husband in Islam?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, women, wali

please provide the answer and if possible the reference

1 : what rights does a girl has to choose her husband by her self ??

2 : up to what limit and what right her parents have over her will ??

3 : is it ok for a girl to deny the choice chosen by her parents ??

4 : is it ok for the parents to deny the choice chosen by their daughter ??

I have also heard ,that a choice of a girl is superior to her parents , how right is this ??

Answer (score 3):

As Salamu Alikum,

1. A woman has all the rights to choose a good husband for her as long as he's a Muslim. However, she cannot choose a Kafir as a husband.
2. No one has the right to force a girl to marry anyone, but at the same time she does not have the right to get married without her guardian’s permission. The presence of the wali (guardian) is one of the conditions of marriage, and a woman’s marriage is not valid unless this condition is met. This is the correct view and is the view of the majority of scholars.(is this what you are asking?)
3. Yes it is allowed for a girl to refuse her parents choice.
4. the parents may like or dislike their daughter's choice, but as long as the person is good, the girl can marry.

Ya, the girl's will is superior to the will of parents, from the hadith:  A woman named Khansa Bint Khidam once came to the Prophet and complained: 
"My father has forced me to marry my cousin in order to raise his own status (in the eyes of the people)." The Prophet told her that she was free to dissolve this marriage and choose whomever she wished to marry. She replied, "I accept my father's choice, but my aim was to let the women know that fathers have no right to interfere in the marriage." (Ahmad, Nasa'i and Ibn Majah)

The guardian of the girl whether her father, brother or uncle plays an important role in her marriage such as finding a suitable match for her. But under no circumstance does this allow him to force his choice on her against her wishes. She is free to accept or reject his choice, or make her own choice.

check this out:

http://www.islamicfinder.org/articles/article.php?id=411

http://islamqa.info/en/22760

http://www.islamicity.com/dialogue/Q676.HTM

Answer (score 0):

Your parents cant force you to marry a man you dont like. But you need the
permission of your Father to marry. If the man you like is a believing moslem then 
your Father has to accept him.

here the hadith bukhari

Narrated 'Aisha:

Allah's Apostle said, "It is essential to have the consent of a virgin (for the marriage). I said, "A virgin feels shy." The Prophet; said, "Her silence means her consent." Some people said, "If a man falls in love with an orphan slave girl or a virgin and she refuses (him) and then he makes a trick by bringing two false witnesses to testify that he has married her, and then she attains the age of puberty and agrees to marry him and the judge accepts the false witness and the husband knows that the witnesses were false ones, he may consummate his marriage."

Comment: what do u mean , Father has to agree ??

Answer (score 0):

In Quran God says donot off to your parents .which means donot hurt their feelings .they cannot force to marry against her will. That does not mean she can have friendship with namehrum and marry. This is lecherous and goes against the commandment of God which stops women friendship with men as in atheist  society۰If she marries against her parents approval she will terribly hurt her parents feeling for life who brought her up with love and affection. It also goes against the will of where He mentions about parents just after His obedience in quaan. These are the mislead people  who say otherwise . God give them hadaya . Any hadees which goes against quraan commandment is weak concocted and fabricated hadees which should be rejected. God give these people hadaya. Amen.e. God give them hadaya. Amen

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].